# Grouped dplyr::mutate incorrectly returns vectors of lubridate intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, r-s4, lubridate

I have a set of observation pairs that I want to label with the intervals between their `time`s. (In the real dataset, these observation pairs represent entry and exit microphone calibrations.)

```
# R version 3.2.3
library(lubridate) ## Version 1.5.6
library(dplyr) ## Version 0.5.0

data <- data.frame(
    group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
    type = rep(c("start", "end"), 3),
    time = ymd_hms("2016-06-01 01:00:00") + c(0,1,3,6,12,18),
    someAttribute = runif(6)
)

data
##   group  type                time someAttribute
## 1     1 start 2016-06-01 01:00:00     0.2540128
## 2     1   end 2016-06-01 01:00:01     0.6845078
## 3     2 start 2016-06-01 01:00:03     0.3576477
## 4     2   end 2016-06-01 01:00:06     0.1223582
## 5     3 start 2016-06-01 01:00:12     0.2715063
## 6     3   end 2016-06-01 01:00:18     0.6392607
```

I include a dummy `someAttribute` in this example to emphasize that a simple solution like `tidyr::spread()` would make a mess of the attributes that belong to each row in `data`.

I have a function that makes the intervals, and I apply it by group with `dplyr`:

```
makeTwoIntervals <- function(twoDatetimes) {
    return(rep(interval(twoDatetimes[1], twoDatetimes[2]), 2))
}

data2 <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(intervals = makeTwoIntervals(time))

data2$intervals
## [1] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [2] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [3] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC
## [4] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC
## [5] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
## [6] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
```

These values are not what I expected to get. The correct times are passed to my function, and it creates the correct two-element vector of intervals for return, but when this vector is passed back to `mutate`, something bad happens. Taking a closer look:

```
str(data2$intervals)
## Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
##   ..@ .Data: num [1:6] 1 1 3 3 6 6
##   ..@ start: POSIXct[1:2], format: "2016-06-01 01:00:00" "2016-06-01 01:00:00"
##   ..@ tzone: chr "UTC"
```

It's not clear to me what went wrong here. These are the results I wanted to see:

```
## Desired result of data2$intervals:
## [1] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [2] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [3] 2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
## [4] 2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
## [5] 2016-06-01 01:00:12 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:18 UTC
## [6] 2016-06-01 01:00:12 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:18 UTC
```

Could anyone offer some insight into what went wrong, or how I could achieve the desired result? Am I misusing `mutate`, or is it just not designed to handle objects like `lubridate::Interval`?

Comment: This was recently filed as an issue, [#1777](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1777) on the data.table project page as well, and I suggest a workaround there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround based on @Arun's `data.table` workaround ([#1777](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1777)), but in `dplyr` language:

```
data2 <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(ranges = list(range(time)))
data3 <- data2 %>% mutate(intervals = list(interval(ranges[[1]][1], ranges[[1]][2])))
data3$intervals2 <- do.call("c", data3$intervals)

data3$intervals2
## [1] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [2] 2016-06-01 01:00:00 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:01 UTC
## [3] 2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
## [4] 2016-06-01 01:00:03 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:06 UTC
## [5] 2016-06-01 01:00:12 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:18 UTC
## [6] 2016-06-01 01:00:12 UTC--2016-06-01 01:00:18 UTC
```

Not totally satisfying, but it works. Thanks for the tip, @Arun.